Automapper mapping to derived type based on predicate when base class is not abstract
I need to map a model to a derived class based on a condition, but otherwise map to another class.
for example if I have these classes
class Shape
{
}

class Rectangle : BasePolygon
{
}

class Square : Rectangle
{
}

This mapping profile
CreateMap<Shape, Rectangle>();
CreateMap<Shape, Square>();

How would I call var result = mapper.Map<List<Rectangle>>(myShapes); and have the squares in result keep their type information of Square?
I tried using ConstructUsing but it created an infinite loop due to the circular reference in the else statement.
CreateMap<Shape, Rectangle>()
    .ConstructUsing((src, context) => 
    {
        if (src.IsSquarePredicate)
            return context.Mapper.Map<Square>(src);
        else
            return context.Mapper.Map<Rectangle>(src);
    });

I could setup a ConstructUsing on a base class, but then anytime I add a new shape, I have to update that mapping profile. Is there a way to do it so it requires less maintenance as well?
